# Equation for a Locus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, locus

[image: GeoGebra Scheme for Said Locus]

I'm wondering how to go about finding the equation that defines this locus. In short, the locus is all the points the same distance from the closest point on $e^x - 1$ as $(0,1)$. The setup in GeoGebra also lets me change the function it depends on easily which produces very interesting results for almost every function (for a straight line, it produces a parabola).

Comment: can you express the distance from any point $(x,y)$ to any point $(x',e^{x'}-1)$?

Comment: One of the definitions of the parabola is the locus of a point which is equidistant from a fixed point (the *focus*) and a straight line (the *directrix*),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance from any point $P(x, y)$ on the required locus to the fixed point $Q(0, 1)$ is given by $$PQ^2=x^2+(y-1)^2$$
The distance from the same point $P(x, y)$ to a point $T$ on the given curve $(t, e^t-1)$ is given by
$$s=PT^2=(x-t)^2+z^2$$
where $z=y-e^t+1$ hence $y-1=z+e^t-2$.

The point $T$ is closest to $P$ when $s$ is a minimum wrt $t$ :
$$\frac{ds}{dt}=2(x-t)(-1)+2z(-e^t)=0$$
$$x=t-ze^t$$

The required locus is defined by $PQ^2=PT^2$ :
$$x^2+(y-1)^2=(x-t)^2+z^2$$

Substitute to eliminate $x, y$ leaving an equation in $z, t$ :
$$(t-ze^t)^2+(z+e^t-2)^2=z^2e^{2t}+z^2$$
$$t^2-2tze^t+e^{2t}+4-2(ze^t-2z-2e^t)=0$$
$$z=\frac{t^2+(e^t-2)^2}{2[(t-1)e^t+2]}$$

Co-ordinates of points on the locus can be obtained in terms of parameters $t$ and $z(t)$ :

$$x=t-ze^t, y=z+e^t-1$$